# "1 != 1" error from immutable react unit tests

Tags: mocha.js, react-redux, chai

Running some unit tests while learning react and I'm seeing this fail message

```
expected Map { "items": List [] } to equal Map { "items": List [] }
```

My question is... what? I'm using `fromJS` for both the action and evaluation but this matches the tutorial I'm following and seems to be working elsewhere in the project. What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe compare the `items` length inside `Map`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an object of type `Map`, and you are comparing if both have the same reference in memory. Since they don't have the same reference in memory because each object was created with the keyword `new Map(...` then `first Map object with memory reference XYZ` != `second Map object with memory reference ABC`.

I hope it makes sense.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't create them with new Map(), does fromJS use that behind the scenes? Even if so I don't think this is the issue, as I said this pattern is copied from a tutorial and working elsewhere in the app.

Comment: That's what Immutable does. Every time you modify an object it will create a  new one with the changes you made and will have a different reference in memory. And if that pattern is working everywhere else, then the problem is somewhere else in the code but being reflected in that `expect()` call

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was missing `chai.use(chaiImmutable);` from my test entry point. Jorge's assertion was correct, but apparently this line is what allows value-wise comparison of immutable objects.

Thanks!